# Как написать sql запрос чтобы получить элементы у которых поле field входит в массив arr?

Tags: postgresql

Есть таблица(table) у которой есть колонка body с типом jsonb в которой у элементов есть поле field. В нем хранится массив uuid.

И есть массив(arr) uuid = ['5aad8e68-7424-4038-b5ae-782e2be6ea7d', 'f6309c42-c7be-4d94-b4ba-d78e0cf72314']

Как написать sql запрос чтобы получить элементы у которых поле field входит в массив arr?

```
select * 
from table 
where ????;
```

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html , операторы `jsonb ->> text` и `jsonb ?| text[]` либо `jsonb ?& text[]`

Answer (score 1):

```
select * 
from table
where body->'field' <@ '["5aad8e68-7424-4038-b5ae-782e2be6ea7d", "f6309c42-c7be-4d94-b4ba-d78e0cf72314"]';
```

Comment: Старайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы (кнопка [edit])